# Chain Assignment of varaible in php class do not work

Tags: php, variable-assignment, chain

I had not used this before and I start using chain assignment for first time and i got problem.

my code is

```
class test
{
    private $col1 = $col2 = $col3 = $col4 = "";
}
```

I got php error as follow
syntax error, unexpected '$col2' (T_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use comma like this:

```
class test
{
    private $col1, $col2, $col3, $col4 = "";
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can upvote and mark this as close/done. Happy Coding!